# nslookup behind proxy dont't work

Tags: bash, dns, nslookup

I tested nslookup to check my domain name in DNS at home without proxy, no problem, it works.

> root@root:/home/root# nslookup 'ep1.transfer.globus.org' 8.8.4.4
>   Server:       8.8.4.4 Address:    8.8.4.4#53
>
> Non-authoritative answer: Name:   ep1.transfer.globus.org Address:
>   52.4.241.164

But when I tried it at work behind proxy it doesn't work

> root@root:/home/root# nslookup 'ep1.transfer.globus.org' 8.8.4.4 ;;
>   connection timed out; no servers could be reached

any solution to bypass my proxy ?

thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 1):

You should not need to specify a server when doing a query. Just use

```
# nslookup ep1.transfer.globus.org
```

If your configured server (/etc/resolv.conf) cannot answer the query it will pass it up to someone who can. It would not be uncommon for a firewall to block direct DNS queries to any server other than the authoritative one inside the firewall.

Comment: Thanks, 
I' followin a tuto to install this globus server endpoint here is the tuto https://docs.globus.org/globus-connect-server-installation-guide/#check_hostname_external_dns_resolution
the problem that it works without proxy, so why not when I'm behind it ?

PS: I disabled the firewall

Comment: You disabled the firewall on you work machine itself or your company's firewall between the internet and intranet?

Comment: Doubt that will help - you need outgoing port 53 open on your company firewall/proxy if you want to bypass the internal DNS. What happens if you don't specify Google's DNS server and just type 'nslookup ep1.transfer.globus.org'